# How To Use Tags In Vim For Notes

Tags: tags

**Backstory:** So there is all these notes app like Evernote Onenote... but I do not want to be locked into a system and only are going to use my laptop. So I thought why not use vim to edit markdown files which are saved in a Dropbox folder. And it would be nice to have tags working on it as well but there are a few problems with tags, I can't easily rename them.

**Problem:** How can I change tags and files without changing the tag location? Eg a tag called `flying potato project` and I want to rename it to `potato express` and change the file from `potato-idea.md` to `potato-idea-for-ever.md` but still keeping the tag location.

Maybe something with ids? Eg the tag for the text about potato express could be `@253`

**INFO EDIT:**
If you don't know what vim tags is then have a look at this website http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Browsing_programs_with_tags

**Edit**:
This post has also been posted here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47932055/use-tags-in-vim-for-notes and
https://superuser.com/questions/1279464/how-to-use-tags-in-vim-for-notes

Comment: Please note that this is x-posted from https://superuser.com/q/1279464/572612

Comment: Whats wrong with re-indexing the tags?

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble It is fine if you can do it everywhere at ones. It's just a problem if some file I don't use often have a tag that is outdated.

Comment: @HerbWolfe It is also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47932055/use-tags-in-vim-for-notes but it properly belongs here

Comment: You shouldn't be cross posting the question, but when you do, you should refer back to the original posts.

Comment: Using eg exuberant ctags, its a matter of `ctags -R .` I believe (assuming youre in a directory containing your notes hierarchy)

Comment: @HerbWolfe Just added the links to the other posts on all the posts

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble If you do that you just install ctags which added tags to all functions in code and some other things but I can't use that for notes... But thanks for the idea

Comment: Hm. I thought ctags had support for markdown or similar text formats. Perhaps i was wrong

Answer (score 1):

This is not strictly speaking an answer to your question, but there are several plugins that provides a note-taking system for Vim, for instance:

- http://vimwiki.github.io/
- http://peterodding.com/code/vim/notes/

Answer (score 0):

I've been experimenting with using Vim keyboard bindings for OneNote 2016 using this library: https://github.com/rcmdnk/vim_ahk

Blogged about it here: https://davemateer.com/2020/04/10/OneNote-with-Vim

It is so nice to be able to edit in OneNote using Vim bindings!

**Update 23rd April 2020**
Thanks to @D.Ben Knoble for pointing out that I really should answer this more fully. So this isn't really an answer to the question but rather a thought that OneNote 2016 (which is now supported again) with Vim bindings work quite well:

- Use Autohotkey
- Use bindings to give a Vim like experience
- Use https://github.com/ililim/dual-key-remap to map the caps-lock key to escape (which is a C library, and I found preferable to another Autohotkey binding)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se], Dave! Thanks for sharing the knowledge. It would be great if you could put the relevant info from the links in your post, both to show how you answer the question and to avoid link rot. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @D.BenKnoble - have updated the answer.